# How to install Latex in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: apt, latex

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my Computer. I want to install Latex on my Desktop but i am unable to install it.

I first tried to install using following command:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

but i am getting following error:

```
E: Package 'texlive-full' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 36):

You should try to update your APT cache before:
`sudo apt-get update`

Then try again `sudo apt-get install texlive-full`

By the way, you can list all texlive available packages by doing:
`apt-cache search --names-only texlive`

Comment: FYI, this will require 4GB of space on install. You can install less if needed.

Answer (score 0):

...and if Xavier's suggestion does not resolve your issue, make sure you have the universe repository enabled.

To enable it, you can perform the task as outlined in this post:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=179

Then, update your APT cache with `sudo apt-get update`.