# Unable to install TexLive on Ubuntu, permission problems

Tags: permissions, software-installation, latex, texlive

I tried to follow this link to install texlive:
https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

But what I have, when I enter the command 'i' is the following error:

```
Installing to: /usr/local/texlive/2014
./install-tl: open(>/usr/local/texlive/2014/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb.tmp) failed: Permission denied at tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm line 427, <STDIN> line 1.
```

For sure it is a permission problem and I tried already doing
sudo ./install-tl and what I get is :

```
Installing to: /usr/local/texlive/2014
Installing [0001/2943, time/total: ??:??/??:??]: 12many [376k]
chdir(/udd/fschiano/install-tl-20141214) failed: Permission denied at tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 2340, <STDIN> line 1.
```

Someone can help me please?

Comment: Why don't you merely install the `texlive-full` package ? See  [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/392102/how-to-install-latex-in-ubuntu-13-10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem installing texlive-full as suggested by **Xavier**.

I know it is not the best solution for everyone because it is a lot of files but it worked for me.

So the command is the following:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

I hope it will help someone else.

Answer (score 2):

I am new to Linux and LaTex, so apologies in advance if the rest of this is of no use to you.

I just installed texlive yesterday, and I do not remember having to enter 'i'. I had the reverse problem, not being able to install the full package because of errors during installation. I am running Linux on a small board called cubieboard2, that may be missing hardware or drivers required for some packages in the full version of texlive.

My commands were the following:

```
apt-get install texlive
apt-get install texmaker
```

When you come across a missing LaTex command, in my case it was *fullpage*, you can use apt-file to look for it:

```
apt-get install apt-file
apt-file -x search '/fullpage.sty$'
```

If it finds the file, it should respond like this:

```
texlive-latex-extra: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/preprint/fullpage.sty
```

saying that it found 'fullpage.sty' in package 'texlive-latex-extra', so...

```
apt-get install texlive-latex-extra
```

Note: After running

```
apt-file -x search '/fullpage.sty$'
```

it may ask you to run some updating command first. I don't remember the command, but it will tell you.